# Check if string contains a character combination and replace if it does in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have possible string combinations:

```
$string1 = '[variation-price] for product one.';
$string2 = 'Product two consists of [variation-parts]';
$string3 = 'Simple product';

$replace = 'Contains variations';
```

I need to check every string if it contains `[variation-` and if it does, replace the whole word (f.x. `[variation-price]`) with `$replace`.

I have tried various functions, bet the problem is that I do not know where exactly in a string variation may appear or how long it will be.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: `str_replace()` did you check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\[variation-.*?\]` regex with `preg_replace()`:

```
preg_replace("/\[variation-.*?\]/", $replace, $string1)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/MtNZ3L